# Set webpack environmental variable for apache2

Tags: node.js, apache, webpack, vue.js, typo3

Is it possible to fetch a webpack envvar outside the node / js scope?

I'm developing with vueJS and TYPO3 and want to load the JS files from node server, when it runs. Otherwise, I want to load the built JS files from the project folder. 
TYPO3 has conditions for file loading, in dependence of an Apache envvar.

```
SetEnv TYPO3_CONTEXT Development
```

Questions:

1. Is it possible to set an apache2 envvar when launching a node devserver by webpack?
2. If not, is it possible to hook in that process and write a temporary htaccess file with the var in it, place it in a specific directory and delete it, when I stop the node server?

Background:

In TYPO3, js and css includes are configured by TypeScript. 
In Prod Env:

```
page.includeJSFooter.app = path/to/build/name.js
```

This load can be changed by condition:

```
[applicationContext = Development]
page.includeJSFooter.app = http://192.168.100.38:8080/app.build.js
[end]
```

Now I want to set this context, as soon as I start my node dev server that builds the files on the fly:

```
webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is possible but as a solution I would propose to implement a custom condition (described here in the manual https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/TypoScriptSyntax/TypoScriptParserApi/CustomConditions.html) and check within that e.g with a request if the node server is responding.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Georg and all others,

a custom condition would be a solution, but I don't want to influence the production environment (e.g. pinging for a response from node server).

I made it with two shell scripts, executed by webpack-shell-plugin. 
The first script is triggered "onBuildStart", looking for an .htaccess file and adding

```
SetEnv TYPO3_CONTEXT Development/NodeServer
```

to the end of the file.
Unfortunately there is no event fired when the node server is shut down. As a workaround, I added a new npm run script, which just executes a shell script to delete that line from .htaccess again.

I guess there is a besser solution, but at this time, it solves my (very little) problem to avoid changing the JS includes every time I start to develop.